# Why is my callback not working with the axios library?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a small Spotify app that I am trying to convert to use the `axios` `http` library.  I am having an issue with the callback when logging in.  Up to this point I have been using `request` like is in all of the `Spotify` documentation.  Everything works fine with `request`, but even though everything looks the same with `axios`, I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.  Here is my code to make the `http` request:

```
var authOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET).toString('base64'))
    },
    json: true
};

axios(authOptions).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

I can pass the same `authOptions` object to the `request` library everything works fine.  Here is my request from `axios` logged out to the console.

```
{ 
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  form: 
   { code: 'changedthecode',
     redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/callback',
     grant_type: 'authorization_code' },
  headers: { Authorization: 'Basic changedthecode=' },
  json: true,
  timeout: 0,
  transformRequest: [ [Function] ],
  transformResponse: [ [Function] ],
  withCredentials: undefined 
}
```

And here is my response with the `axios` library:

```
{ data: { error: 'server_error' },
  status: 500,
  statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
  headers: 
   { server: 'nginx',
     date: 'Fri, 04 Dec 2015 14:48:06 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'content-length': '24',
     connection: 'close' },
  config: 
   { method: 'POST',
     headers: { Authorization: 'Basic changedthecode' },
     timeout: 0,
     transformRequest: [ [Function] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function] ],
     url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
     form: 
      { code: 'changedthecode',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8888/callback',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code' },
     json: true,
     withCredentials: undefined } 
}
```

The only option that I didn't know about from `axios` was `withCredentials`, and it didn't work when it was set to `false` or `true`.  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I was posting a form and was not encoding it when going across the wire and I was not setting the `Content-Type`.  I changed my `authOptions` to:

```
var authOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    data: querystring.stringify({
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: refreshToken
        }),
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET).toString('base64')),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    json: true
};
```

and everything worked fine.